# I need a software like intra but for PC to bypass my country's (Indonesia) firewall

Tags: dns, website-blocker

I can't access reddit in Indonesia normally. No one can. But for android there is a software that take care of it. It's called Intra.

Install Intra turn it on tada it works.

In PC I tried to use simpleDNScrypt.

It works for a while

However, now every time I tried to access reddit I got this screen

[image]

I do not understand what Intra really did. Simply changing DNS server? Well. Simplednscrypt do far more than that and fail. Yet Intra in my android phone works fine.

I wonder if there is a software like Intra for windows 10

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that [Intra uses](https://support.getintra.org/s/article/Using-Intra-App?language=en_US) [DNS over HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_over_HTTPS) to encrypt your data.
If it's possible for you to upgrade to Windows 11, then you can have the feature natively in the settings. [Here is a guide on HowToGeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/765940/how-to-enable-dns-over-https-on-windows-11/) for activating that setting. If upgrading to Windows 11 is not an option, newer versions of Windows 10 seem to also support this feature ([Build 20185 or later](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2020/08/05/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-20185/)). [Here is a blogpost](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/networking-blog/windows-insiders-gain-new-dns-over-https-controls/ba-p/2494644) for how to enable it in the settings. Finally, depending on your router, some manufacturers offer that feature on the network level. Try searching for `[your router brand] DNS over HTTPS` to see if there is a support page for that. You might also want to look into a good VPN to mask your location, but that's a different topic.